# Accessing Property of an Object which is in HashMap Java Android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am pulling data from db and puting it into an hashmap.

```
HashMap<String,Object> players= new HashMap();
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            players.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue());
        }
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : players.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("asd","Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }
```

Log.d output is :

```
D/asd: Key = lastpeony, Value = {lat=40.89, long=29.37, avatar=dino}
D/asd: Key = lifesuxtr, Value = {lat=40.8901765, long=29.377306, avatar =petyr}
```

what i am trying to do is access lat long and avatar values for each key.
How do i do that  ? 
Because later i am going to use those values to draw markers on a map.

thanks

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract something specific(latti or longi) within each value of `HashMap<String,Object> players` map, the value type should be more specific than just `Object` type. So, instead of using `HashMap<String,Object>` to store `players`, use `HashMap<String,SomeSpecificType>`

Comment: Can you post the class or interface definition of `DataSnapshot`, in your question? That will be real helpful for anyone looking to answer you problem

Answer (score 0):

You use hashmap .get [https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)](http://.get)

```
String key = "lastpeon";
Object value = players.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
HashMap<String,Object> players= new HashMap();
```

to

```
HashMap<String,Map<String,Object>> players= new HashMap<>();
```

Then initialize the `Map` with:

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    players.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), (Map<String,Object>)childSnapshot.getValue());
}
```

Then you can iterate over the inner `Map`s:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String,Object>> entry : players.entrySet()) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> ientry : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        Log.d("asd","Key = " + ientry.getKey() + ", Value = " + ientry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: incompatible types       https://image.prntscr.com/image/w-yjAu1eTQiDUZKG1dd8KQ.png